# Calculate correct dose for pet

Tags: linear-algebra

if I have a solution that contains 750 mg of curcumin in 10 ml of water and I want to give a dose that is equal to 25 mg curcumin How many ml do I give?

Need to medicate my cat and I need to be sure to give correct dose. Thanks

Comment: If your statements are all correct, you need to give your cat 25 of the 750 mg; that's 1/30 of the total. That'll be a good deal less than 1ml -- not much at all ... indeed, such a small amount that it's hard to believe you could reliably give your cat exactly that amount.  But **you'd be crazy to trust me**; I'm just a random person on the internet who happens to think he knows about numbers! I recommend that you ask the person who prescribed the medication, who might be able to speak with real authority (and about whom you can complain if s/he tells you something wrong).

Comment: I can confirm the math (less than 1ml, specifically $\frac13$ of a ml) for what it's worth it, but I am also a random person on the internet... I just hope your cat will be ok.

Comment: Please don't trust us with your cat's health.  **None of the information you obtain from this site should be interpreted as medical advice.**  We are not vets and are not qualified to advise you medically on how to medicate your cat.  You should always seek advice from someone that is qualified to give it -- in this case, that would be the vet that prescribed the medication.

Answer (score 1):

We apply the related ratios

$$\frac{750\,\,\text{mg}}{10\,\,\text{m}\ell}=\frac{25\,\,\text{mg}}{x}$$

whereupon solving for x gives

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=\frac{10\,\,\text{m}\ell\times 25\,\,\text{mg}}{750\,\,\text{mg}}=\frac13\,\,\text{m}\ell}$$

Comment: And I hope that your cat gets well!!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.